# suzuki 85 lt 185 wont start

Tags: suzuki

My quad was overheating bad and I didn't think about it and opened the oil cap like an idiot and it sprayed oil and smoke everywhere so I hurried up and shut it off and I tried to start it after it cooled and I added some oil. I had to replace the pull string it burned it right off and now it will not fire up no matter how many times I pull the start string.

I hope the oil shooting out didn't ruin it. Spark plug maybe? It was kinda dirty and I cleaned it off but I don't know.

Comment: The hot oil got on the pull string and melted it?   Apparently you replaced it as you describe continued pulling to attempt a start.  The oil shooting out of the crank case cover while running more than likely did NOT ruin it.  Have you removed the sparkplug and tested to see if you are actually getting any spark?

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?  If so, please provide a bit of additional information related to the comment above and perhaps an answer can begin to get formulated.